# How to insert multiple lines into MySQL from Python at once (bulk insert) and ignore eventual errors?

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

I need to perform bulk inserts into a MySQL database from a Python 2.7 application. Due to performance reasons, I need to perform bulk inserts of thousands of lines at once.

The only way I could find to do this is to use MySQLCursor.executemany.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html

However, if one single line fails to insert, MySQLCursor raises an exception and I lose the entire batch.

Does anybody know a way to achieve this and ignore errors that might eventually arise from a few single inserts inside large batches?

Comment: Have a look at [`load data infile ...`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html), it was built exactly for this.

Comment: Well, "load data infile" is used to load contents from text files to the database. In my case, the data comes from elsewhere; therefore, I need to do this with Python code only.

Comment: Therein lies your choice. I would seriously consider your reliance on Python in this case and challenge the assumption that this needs to be done in Python.